Benchmark WebGL Application with old Monitor
I have written a small WebGL application that I would like to benchmark. My problem is that my monitor is only 60Hz, so even with the smallest instances I get max 60 FPS, but I know it could be more.
Is there a way to benchmark my program without buying a new monitor? Any changes in my Ubuntu settings (22.04) or my browser settings? Would it be possible to change something in my WebGL code? To create the animation I use
requestAnimationFrame()

I have already tried to set a higher frame rate in xandr. But with every setting I tried it just said that it is not available.
Any ideas?

What is your benchmark trying to prove? If something is already running at a smooth 60fps then it probably isn't a good candidate for optimization...

@Dai It's running very smooth. I need the benchmark for a project at uni to show that this implementation is actually better than the trivial solution.

...can you try to run your WebGL JS in a headless environment (where there wouldn't be a vsync-capped frame-rate) - i.e. outside of Chrome (but still in V8) - such as in a WebGL-enabled instance of Node?

Now I am getting some strange errors. I'll try to figure it out. Thanks for the idea!
